# Let's get critical: Mar 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Magento Stack Exchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Add Category tree in custom extension](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14833/add-category-tree-in-custom-extension)

**Net Score: 11** (Excellent: 12, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Do Billing Agreements even work with Paypal Payflow Pro?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14607/do-billing-agreements-even-work-with-paypal-payflow-pro)

**Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [conditionally change layout template for catalogsearch](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14525/conditionally-change-layout-template-for-catalogsearch)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Is there a recommended way to temporarily suspend ordering?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15382/is-there-a-recommended-way-to-temporarily-suspend-ordering)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Redirect to same product URL after error from Add To Cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14738/add-to-cart-error-redirect-issue-magento)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [how to add shipping method options](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14695/how-to-add-shipping-method-options)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to change Magento's default date in calendar?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14643/how-to-change-magentos-default-date-in-calendar)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [flow of method call in payment method](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15593/flow-of-method-call-in-payment-method)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [How to access custom table/attributes using the ORM?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15525/how-to-access-custom-table-attributes-using-the-orm)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [how to make dynamic two-column layout for custom options](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15404/how-to-make-dynamic-two-column-layout-for-custom-options)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 6)

---